# How to get rid of the line labels in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts to create a graph. I am able to display the output but I am unable to remove the label . I am not able to figure out how to get rid of the label.

```js
    //document.getElementById('container').style.visibility='visible';
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stock Price',
        },
        subtitle: {
             text: '<a style=\"color:blue;\" href=\"https://www.alphavantage.co\">Source: Alpha Vantage</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        showLastLabel: true,
        endOnTick: true,
            categories: [ "05/30", "05/31", "06/01", "06/02", "06/05", "06/06", "06/07", "06/08"],
              labels:{
              step:2},
             
             
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'Stock Price'
            },
             labels: {
            enabled: false
        },
           
             },{
            title: {
                text: 'Volume ',
                },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}m',
                enabled: false,
            },
            opposite:true,
            
        }],
        plotOptions: {
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
        
            line: {
                
                enableMouseTracking: false
            },
              series: {
            marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },}
            
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle'
        },
        series: [{
        labels: {
            enabled: false,
        },
            name: 'Tokyo',
            type: 'area',
            color: '#F66464',
            
            
            data: [4,5,6,7,8,9,1],
             
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            type: 'column',
            color: '#FFFFFF',
             yAxis: 1,
            data: [1,2,3],
            
    
        }]
    });
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

I tried disabling the label but it doesn't seem to work. 
 I want to get rid of the labels ("Tokyo" written in white) in the following output. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You were so close. The label can be removed by including this:

```
label: {
    enabled: false,
},
```

in your series, or in the `plotOptions` if you want to remove all labels.

You typed `labels` with an **s**, which is unfortunately not correct.

**API on series label**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.label

Answer (score 0):

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.label

Go through this docs.
You need to make series.lable.enabled = false;